How to send an API Key authorization method in a POST request
I have been trying to send a token via API Key Authorization method but I've been getting an unauthorized error:
{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.NoWriteNoSeekStreamContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Wed, 23 Oct 2024 16:35:03 GMT
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}}

This is my code:
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Data.BQL;
using PX.Data.BQL.Fluent;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.Common.Extensions;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using RiverlandDesarrolloV231;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using PX.Concurrency;

namespace PX.Objects.IN
{
    public class INReceiptEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.IN.INReceiptEntry>
    {
        #region Event Handlers

        public PXAction<INRegister> PrenderAntena;
        [PXButton]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Prender Antena", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select, Enabled = true)]
        protected virtual IEnumerable prenderAntena(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            this.Base.LongOperationManager.StartAsyncOperation((ct) => Prueba());
            return adapter.Get();
        }

        public static async Task Prueba()
        {
            var credentials = new Credentials
            {
                usuario = new FieldValue { value = "MyUser" },
                contraseña = new FieldValue { value = "MyPassword" }
            };

            string jsonPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(credentials, Formatting.Indented);
            string url = "MyUrl";

            var handler = new WinHttpHandler();

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                try
                {
                    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
                    requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(jsonPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);

                    PXTrace.WriteInformation("Estado de la respuesta: " + response.StatusCode.ToString());

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        PXTrace.WriteInformation("Respuesta del servidor: " + responseContent.ToString());

                        var apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(responseContent);
                        PXTrace.WriteInformation("API key: " + apiResponse.apiKey?.value.ToString());
                        
                        var receiptNbr = new ReceiptNbr
                        {
                            numeroSolicitud = new FieldValue { value = "0987654" }
                        };

                        string jsonPayload2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(receiptNbr, Formatting.Indented);
                        string url2 = "MyUrl";

                        var handler2 = new WinHttpHandler();

                        using (HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient(handler2))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var requestMessage2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url2);
                                requestMessage2.Content = new StringContent(jsonPayload2, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                                
                                client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Api-Key", apiResponse.apiKey?.value);
                               
                                HttpResponseMessage response2 = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage2);

                                PXTrace.WriteInformation("Estado de la respuesta: " + response2.StatusCode.ToString());

                                if (response2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                                {
                                    string responseContent2 = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                                    PXTrace.WriteInformation("Respuesta del servidor: " + responseContent2.ToString());

                                    var apiResponse2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(responseContent2);
                                    PXTrace.WriteInformation("API key: " + apiResponse2.apiKey?.value.ToString());
                                }
                            }
                            catch (HttpRequestException httpEx2)
                            {
                                PXTrace.WriteInformation("Excepción en la solicitud HTTP : " + httpEx2.Message);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex2)
                            {
                                PXTrace.WriteInformation("Excepción en la solicitud : " + ex2.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string errorResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        PXTrace.WriteInformation("Error en la solicitud: " + response.ReasonPhrase.ToString(), "Contenido: " + errorResponse);
                    }
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException httpEx)
                {
                    PXTrace.WriteInformation("Excepción en la solicitud HTTP : " + httpEx.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    PXTrace.WriteInformation("Excepción en la solicitud : " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        public class ApiResponse
        {
            public ApiKey apiKey { get; set; }
        }

        public class ApiKey
        {
            public string value { get; set; }
        }

        public class Credentials
        {
            public FieldValue usuario { get; set; }
            public FieldValue contraseña { get; set; }
        }

        public class FieldValue
        {
            public string value { get; set; }
        }

        public class ReceiptNbr
        {
            public FieldValue numeroSolicitud { get; set; }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}

I added this line of code but it may not be working properly:
client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Api-Key", apiResponse.apiKey?.value);
All this works well in Postman:

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?
